# My songs I put on my Micro SD Card does not appear on Samsung Galaxy S5!

Tags: samsung, music

Here's what happened. Recently i bought myself a 128 gb Micro SD card. I added all of my music, which takes up 30 gb of the SD Card. When I open up music player i don't see all of the songs i put, only about a handful of them. I only see like 2 GB of the music. Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

Use a file explorer (e.g [ES file explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en) ) and view the contents of your SD card and select and copy your music to the file path  on your internal storage at:

`storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.google.android.music`

Then close and restart Google Play Music and go into the menu and select Refresh. Then your music should show up.

Note: The file path may be slightly different depending on the phone but you'll be looking for the subfolder `com.google.android.music`

Answer (score 0):

Install another app that can search trough your phone for music.

[Shuttle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=another.music.player&hl=hr) for example has option "Rescan library".

[Music Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=music.mediaplayer.musicplayer&hl=hr) scans your songs the firs time you open it and you can search trough folders for your music later.

Comment: Did my answer helped you? @Jalan Pyles

Comment: A little, some songs appeared but not all of them

Answer (score 0):

Try to give them an ID3 Tag and scan again.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer please. The *how to* and *why it should work* ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a different phone (BLU Studio Energy), and it was related to the size of the microSD card.

If less than half of the microSD card was filled, the phone did not recognize it at all! It was a 64GB card, and once I passed 32GB all the music could be seen by the phone.

That may be a terrible bug unique to the BLU phone, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your player only sees songs that are in the android internal media database.

Android has a buildin service that scan the filesystem for media file (photo, music, video) and transfer this info into the media database.

depending on your android version there can be different causes why the new songs are not in the media database (yet)

- the media scanner has not been restarted yet. If you transfered the files via usb it may be helpfull to dismount the sd card and remount it. this will trigger the media scanner. after a while the songs should appear.
- if you can see the songs with a device local filemanager then android and the media scanner can read the files, too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all your songs are in a folder without a .nomedia file and without a .nomedia file in its parent (direct parent, parent of direct parent...) directories.

(The .nomedia file is used to tell media apps not to scan any of the subdirectories of the folder where that file is located. This method is used by apps with video ads for example to prevent the video player from adding ads to its menus.)